# How to make a high-performance matrix algorithm implementation distributed?

Tags: java, performance, matrix, distributed-computing

I have a multithreaded program where the number of cores is the bottleneck for speed. Almost all memory is used by a triangular matrix.

```
long[][] matrix;
```

Actually each element of the matrix is a constant number of bits (256k), so on implementation level it's a 3d matrix (so I can use a primitive type).

Depending on the size of the input, I can make the matrix as large as 500GB, but I'm testing with small inputs to have 4GB. The interesting case is 500GB+ though.

I have a blocking queue of pairs of ints which is initialized with some pairs.

each Thread does the following in pseudocode:

```
while (true) {
    pair = queue.poll()
    if (pair==null) break;
    row1 = matrix.rows[pair[1]];
    row2 = matrix.rows[pair[2]];
    column1 = matrix.columns[pair[1]];
    column2 = matrix.columns[pair[2]];
    (row1',row2',column1',column2') = f(row1, row2, column1, column2);
    matrix.rows[pair[1]] = row1 & row1';
    matrix.rows[pair[2]] = row2 & row2';
    matrix.columns[pair[1]] = column1 & column1';
    matrix.columns[pair[2]] = column2 & column2';
    if (...) {
        queue.enqueue(...)
    }
}
```

Each evaluation of f is about 0.5s but will be longer for bigger inputs. What we see here, that for some number of cpu-cycles, we will only need 2 rows and 2 columns of the matrix. But knowing the speed of for example http requests, it doesn't seem any sense to make this distributed. I'm not sure how memory management is done is cases like this, I've never implented a distributed algorithm. Say if we need a total of 2 GB for the 4 rows and columns for an evaluation of f, does it make sense to use gpu's? I would think that exchanging memory with the host RAM would take too long. Generally how do high-performance distributed algorithms synchronize their memory with the master memory?

Comment: Is there any parallelism in `f` itself? If so, distributing the matrix across the third dimension could make sense. For communication, HTTP doesn't offer you much over plain sockets. But transferring 2 GB may easily take 0.5 second or more. Your queue-based loop is strictly sequentiell, but processing of the next entry may depend only slightly on the previous pair (if different rows/columns get selected) and there might be a way to do most of the work in parallel. `+++` This is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/155925) and knowing the X could help.

Answer (score 0):

A **triangular** matrix could be done with

```
long[][] m = new long[][n];
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    m[i] = new long[i + 1]; // or n - i 
}
```

Easier would be to make a **linear** array and an

```
int index(int row, int column)
```

(An other technique involves **sparse** matrices.)

You are making changes to the same matrix (**in situ**). That puts some requirements to the algorithm.

You can use a **memory mapped** `LongBuffer` for instance, maybe even a memory mapped file: nice for distributed access.

If you are simply considering one computer, several processors, a **java 8** LongStream parallelStream would be simple.

**Distributed computing** should in general not use HTTP as it is (still) slow, and drifting to HTTPS anyway.
A I take it, you do as yet not want to use existing frameworks, go for `Socket`s with timeouts. You need to open ports for client-server exchange (firewalls). Your while-loop, pulling, being replaced with something smarter.

This all is not an answer, but might list some points of attack.

Answer (score 0):

You tagged your question with "java". But to be honest, I would recommend using some library that was developed exactly for the purpose of distributed programming.

One of the most popular (and very sophisticated) ones is [MPI](https://www.open-mpi.org/). It can be used with C/C++ or Fortran. The MPI implementations usually have a good asymptotic complexity for communication routines, i. e., 1) you don't need to implement communication primitives yourself and 2) can expect them to run as fast as possible (especially when you transfer GBs of data it makes a difference if a *gather* or *broadcast* has a complexity of O(n) instead of O(log(n))).

Thus, you might want to consider switching to MPI.